# Url ReWriting in Windows Azure

Tags: windows, azure

```
       I wish to rewrite the Url in the below stated way.
```

i want to rewrite the server name such that the **cloudapp.net** in the cloud application url gets truncated.
Is this possible.

Please somebody guide me on this as iam new to azure.

Thanks,

Pankaj

Comment: Not quite sure what you're saying here, but are you trying to display your own domain name instead of cloudapp.net?

Example:
When someone goes to www.yourwebsitename.com your cloud application loads.

Answer (score 2):

If Jeremy's guess is right, all you need is a CNAME record that maps www.yourwebsitename.com to yourwebsite.cloudapp.net.  See http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure.

If you want to do something else, you'll have to explain what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method suggested above it will mask the domain but not expose any pages underneath. Example.. Site is at blogsmarx.cloudapp.net and he uses a the CNAME Redirect, the user gets forward to bogsmarx.com.

Sounds great but what if he's using QueryString paramters in a page like blogsmarx.cloudapp.net/users.aspx?Username=CurrentUser for example. While it may not be a tidy URL, there may be instances where this needs to be done, rather than just cut off the address after the TLD.